# Trace of a matrix exponential with tensor products, and Von Neumann entropy

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics, entropy

$\def\T{\operatorname{Tr}}$
$\def\1{\mathbb{1}}$
Let $H=H_1\otimes H_2\otimes H_3$ be a finite dimensional Hilbert space, and let $\rho_{123}$ be a self-adjoint matrix with $\rho_{123}\geq 0$ (positive eigenvalues) and $\T{\rho_{123}}=1$, so a density matrix.

Furthermore let $i,j,k\in\{1,2,3\}$ different, and define $\rho_i=\T_{jk}(\rho_{123})$ and $\rho_{jk}=\T_{i}(\rho_{123})$, so for example if $\rho=A_1\otimes B_2\otimes \1_3$ then $\rho_{1}=A_1$ and $\rho_{13}=A_1\otimes\1_3$.

I was reading this paper - https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.1497701?class=pdf (IV, equation 30) - and there is one property that it takes for granted, but I don't find it at all obvious. Even though it doesn't explicitly say it, I think it's implied there's an equality here:

$$
\T\big(e^{\log{\rho_{12}}\otimes\1_3+\1_1\otimes\log{\rho_{23}}} (\log{\rho_{12}}\otimes\1_3+\1_1\otimes\log{\rho_{23}})\big) = \T_{12}\big({\rho_{12} \log{\rho_{12}}}\big) + \T_{23}\big({\rho_{23} \log{\rho_{23}}}\big)
$$

I am trying to prove the following generalization of the above property $(A_{12} = \log(\rho_{12}))$

$$
\T_3( e^{A_{12}\otimes \1_3 + \1_1 \otimes B_{12}}) = e^{A_{12}}.
$$

If this is true then the above proposition follows since

$$
\T(A_{123}\cdot(B_{12}\otimes \1_3))= \T_{12}(\T_3(A_{123})\cdot B_{12}).
$$

I have a feeling like the generalization I am trying to prove is false.

Any different proofs of
$$
\T\big(e^{r_{12}+r_{23}}(r_{12}+r_{23})\big) = \T(e^{r_{12}}r_{12}) + \T(e^{r_{23}}r_{23})
$$
are welcome, and any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT:

If the following is true, it solves all my problems
$$
S(e^{A_{12}\otimes \1_3 + \1_1 \otimes B_{23}}) = S(e^{A_{12}} \otimes e^{B_{23}})
$$
where $S$ is the Von Neumann entropy, since
$$
S(e^{A}\otimes e^{B}) = S(e^{A}) + S(e^B)
$$
and this leads to the desired result.

Note that LHS matrix operates on $H$, while the RHS one has a greater dimension. I don't know how to apply the known formula
$$
e^{A\otimes \1_2 + \1_1\otimes B} = e^{A} \otimes e^{B}
$$
in this case since this equation requires $\1_1$ and $A$ to operate on the same space, and this is not true in my case.

Comment: In general, we have
$$
e^{A \otimes 1 + 1 \otimes B} = e^A \otimes e^B
$$
I suspect that this leads to a proof of your equality. It would be easier to help if you were explicit about the domain/codomain of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but that is true if the dimension of $A$ is the same as dimension of the $1$ that is multiplied with $B$. In my case $A$ operates on $H_1\otimes H_2$ while $1$ operates on $H_1$.

Comment: The domain/codomain of $\rho_{ij}$ is $H_i\otimes H_j$. For $\rho_i$ it's $H_i$ and for $\rho_{123}$ it's $H=H_1\otimes H_2 \otimes H_3$.

Comment: That makes sense now, thanks

Comment: The lower indices show the domain of the operator, it's written for the $\mathbb{1}$'s also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having looked at the original, here's what I think is going on:

The paper instructs:

> A second, more powerful subadditivity inequality...
>   $$
> S(\rho_{123}) \leq S(\rho_{12}) + S(\rho_{23})
> $$
>   under the constraint $\operatorname{tr}(\rho_{123}) = 1$. To prove this, choose $A = \rho_{123}$ and $B = e^{\log\rho_{12} + \log \rho_{23}}$ in Klein's inequality to obtain
>   $$
> -S(\rho_{123})+ S(\rho_{12}) + S(\rho_{23}) \geq 1 - \operatorname{tr} e^{\log\rho_{12} + \log \rho_{23}}
> $$

For reference,

> Klein's inequality:
>   $$
> \operatorname{tr}A(\log A - \log B) \geq \operatorname{tr}(A - B)
> $$

With that, we apply Klein's inequality as follows:
$$
\operatorname{tr}A(\log A - \log B) \geq \operatorname{tr}(A - B) \implies\\
\operatorname{tr}\rho_{123}(\log \rho_{123} - \log [e^{\log\rho_{12} + \log \rho_{23}}]) \geq \operatorname{tr}(\rho_{123} - e^{\log\rho_{12} + \log \rho_{23}}) \implies\\
\operatorname{tr}\rho_{123}(\log \rho_{123}) - 
\operatorname{tr}\rho_{123}(\log\rho_{12} + \log \rho_{23})
\geq \operatorname{tr}(\rho_{123})-
\operatorname{tr}(e^{\log\rho_{12} + \log \rho_{23}}) \implies\\
-S(\rho_{123}) - 
\operatorname{tr}\rho_{123}(\log\rho_{12} + \log \rho_{23})
\geq 1 -
\operatorname{tr}(e^{\log\rho_{12} + \log \rho_{23}}) \implies\\
-S(\rho_{123}) - 
\operatorname{tr}\rho_{123}\log\rho_{12}
- \operatorname{tr}\rho_{123}\log \rho_{23}
\geq 1 -
\operatorname{tr}(e^{\log\rho_{12} + \log \rho_{23}})
$$

With that in mind, it seems to me that the equality being implied is
$$
\operatorname{tr}\rho_{123}\log\rho_{12} = \operatorname{tr}\rho_{12}\log\rho_{12}
$$
Or, more explicitly,
$$
\operatorname{tr}[\rho_{123} \log[\operatorname{tr}_3(\rho_{123}) \otimes 1_3]] = \operatorname{tr}[\operatorname{tr}_3(\rho_{123}) \log[\operatorname{tr}_3(\rho_{123})]]
$$
and similarly for $\rho_{23}$.  It seems to me that this equality indeed holds; let me know if you would like a proof of it.

Comment: About 5 minutes ago as I was having a pause and it hit me that I used $AlogA - BlogB$ in stead of $AlogA - AlogB$ in Klein's inequality. It all makes complete sense now

Comment: Thank you for actually going through the paper to trace what I was looking for. It's kind of unfortunate that such a stupid error in Klein's inequality gave a result that looked half reasonable and made me waste a lot of time on it.

Comment: Glad we figured out what's going on.  For what it's worth, Klein's inequality can also be framed in terms of "relative quantum entropy", as it is done in Watrous's "Theory of Quantum Information". I like this perspective a bit better, and I recommend TQI as a reference.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, TQI is really good !